# Getting infinite loop in firebase cloud function

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am using firestore to store the data in firebase. To get the count i am using cloud function. When i try to add / update / delete an entry in one collection it starts the infinite loop with another collection.
Example:
I am having a user table and agent table when i add/update/delete a user it should get updated in the agent table.

Though i have used separate functions for users and agent still i am getting an infinite loop.can anyone tell me how to resolve it

Query to update the user in user and agent table:

```
 export const addUser = (values) =>
  db
    .collection('users')
    .add(values)
    .then((docRef) => {
      let customer = { customer: {} };
      customer.customer[docRef.id] = {
        id: docRef.id,
        name: values.name,
        commission: values.agent.commission
      };
      let agentId = values.agent.id;
      db.collection('agents')
        .doc(agentId)
        .set(customer, { merge: true });
    });
```

Cloud function for user:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

exports = module.exports = functions.firestore
  .document("users/{userUid}")
  .onWrite(
    (change, context) =>
      new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let dashboardId;
        getDashboardId();
      })
  );

  getDashboardId = () => {
    admin.firestore().collection('dashboard').get().then((snapshot) => {
      if (snapshot.size < 1) {
        dashboardId = admin.firestore().collection('dashboard').doc().id;
      } else {
        snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
          dashboardId = doc.id;
        });
      }
      return updateUser(dashboardId);
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log('error is', error);
    });
  }

  updateUser = (id) => {
    admin.firestore().collection('users').where('isDeleted', '==', false).get().then((snap) => {
      let usersData = {users: snap.size};
      return admin.firestore().collection('dashboard').doc(id).set(usersData, {merge: true});
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log('error is', error);
    });
  }
```

Cloud function for agent:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

exports = module.exports = functions.firestore
  .document("agents/{agentUid}")
  .onWrite(
    (change, context) =>
      new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let dashboardId;
        getDashboardId();
      })
  );

  getDashboardId = () => {
    admin.firestore().collection('dashboard').get().then((snapshot) => {
      if (snapshot.size < 1) {
        dashboardId = admin.firestore().collection('dashboard').doc().id;
      } else {
        snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
          dashboardId = doc.id;
        });
      }
      return updateAgent(dashboardId);
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log('error is', error);
    });
  }

  updateAgent = (id) => {
    admin.firestore().collection('agents').where('isDeleted', '==', false).get().then((snap) => {
      let agentsData = {agents: snap.size};
      return admin.firestore().collection('dashboard').doc(id).set(agentsData, {merge: true});
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log('error is', error);
    });
  }
```

Comment: In general, when a function writes back into the same document that triggered it, you need to detect that case in your function and return early the next time the function triggers for the write you just performed.

Comment: @DougStevenson how could i solve it